# Dimension not Equal to Array Extent Problem

Tags: r

I ran the `R` code to test for `skewness` of a simulated `Gamma` distribution with Monte-Carlo of `1000` a replication of `10, 20, 50, 1000` replicates.

```
## Skewness test for gamma distribution

skew.test <- function (x) {
  m3 <- sum((x-mean(x))^3)/length(x)
  s3 <- sqrt(var(x))^3
  skew <- m3/s3
  ses <- sqrt(6/length(x))
  totest <- skew/ses
  pt(totest,(length(x)-1))
  pval <- pt(totest,(length(x)-1))
  pval
}

out <- t(sapply(c(10, 20, 50, 100), function(x) 
  table(replicate(1000, skew.test(rgamma(n = x, shape = 3, rate = 0.5))) < 0.05)))
row.names(out) <- c(10, 20, 50, 100)
out
```

I got this error message:

> Error in dimnames(x) <- dn :
> length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that all of your values are coming out `TRUE`, so your table is only length-1 (and not a table of `TRUE` and `FALSE` values). There may also be something wrong with your testing logic but I haven't dug in deeply enough to figure it out ...

```r
f2 <- function(x, nsim = 1000, shape = 3) {
  r <- replicate(nsim,
                 skew.test(rgamma(n = x, shape = shape, rate = 0.5)))
  table(factor(r < 0.05, levels=c(TRUE,FALSE)))
}

nvec <- c(10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 1000)
set.seed(101)
out <- t(sapply(nvec, f2))
row.names(out) <- nvec

out2 <- t(sapply(nvec, f2, shape = 1000))
```